# What would cause a rendering to not show in preview mode for non-admins?

Tags: configuration, presentation

I have a rendering that shows fine for admin users but doesn't display for non-admins in preview mode.  This happens on our production server but on our development server the rendering displays fine for both users in preview mode.  We haven't changed the rendering, and I'm not seeing any permission issues for the given item, and it's in the same workflow state on both servers.  I also am not seeing any error in the logs.  Are there any other permissions aside from the item and the rendering that I should look at that might be affecting this?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore are you using? Usually the preview should be the same for everybody when `Preview.AsAnonymous` is set to `true` (which is the default). Does reloading (F5) the preview change anything?